# Integrate Angular-CLI in ASP.NET Core using VS 2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I am having difficulties in integrating Angular-CLI into ASP.NET Core 2 with VS 2017. I do not want to use the provided VS solution where you can use a ready built Angular project which is not CLI. The problem is **I cannot find detailed instructions**. In the meantime while searching I found the following page from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?tabs=visual-studio  where it says it is easy to create an Angular-CLI project if upgrading to .NET Core 2.1.

However, the above does not work for me!!  It just creates what the ready built solution creates. For example, package.json does not have angular.cli.

Any help on the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new templates work just fine for building an application that supports the Angular CLI, but you have to build an application from the command prompt using `dotnet new angular` after [installing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/index#installation) the updated templates.

Building a new Angular application using the Visual Studio application wizard will not use the new templates even after they are installed.

Comment: Sorry but I did not get you. I have installed .NET Core 2.1.4, so according to the documents there is no need for installing the templates.  Of course, I used `dotnet new angular` and the created application is not a CLI one...

Comment: Evidently that technique is not working. Install the templates per the link I provided, and try again. That is what I would do. This worked for me, perfectly.